# Consuming unmanaged DLL functions in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dllimport, unmanaged

I am trying to use an unmanaged DLL of a machine whose function are as follows.

```
int SetTimeouts ( DWORD dwTxTimeout, DWORD dwRxTimeout)
int ListDevices ( DWORD *pArg1, char *pArg2, DWORD dwFlags)
int SetDescription (char *pDescription)
int OpenDevice (int iDeviceType, char* pData, int iDataType)
int GetReturnCode (int iCode, WORD *pCode, char *pData)
int OpenDevice (int iDeviceType, char* pData, int iDataType)
int GetVersion ( BYTE pm, BYTE *pRxData, DWORD *nRxSize )
int Read ( BYTE pm, BYTE *pRxData, DWORD *nRxSize )
int Write ( BYTE pm, BYTE *pTxData, DWORD nTxSize )
int Initialize ( BYTE pm, BYTE *pTxData, DWORD nTxSize, BYTE *pRxData, DWORD *nRxSize )
```

So far i have done this. I have created a static class with the following code.

what does `*` in C++ means? do we need to include any extra keyword to use in .NET?

It is given sometimes before parameter name[`BYTE *pTxData`] and sometimes after Datatype[`char*`]

```
[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int SetTimeouts(uint dwTxTimeout, uint dwRxTimeout);

[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int ListDevices(uint hWnd, char text, uint caption);

[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int SetDescription(char pDescription);

[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int OpenDevice(int iDeviceType, char pData, int iDataType);

[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int GetVersion(int iCode, ushort pCode, byte pData);

[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int Read(byte pm, byte pRxData, uint nRxSize);

[DllImport("MACHINE.dll")]
public static extern int Write(byte pm, byte pTxData, uint nTxSize);
```

Comment: This information can be found in every text book. In every tutorial. Please do basic research.

Comment: I tried searching. But i cannot able to find specifically for that `*` can u please point me to a sample link?

Comment: Read an introductory text on C

Comment: But `DWORD *pArg1` is pointer to `DWORD`. Whitespace not significant so put the `*` next to either type or name or even with spaces either side. Your translation has many other errors. You aren't going to make progress until you learn basics of C.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/